# Una función u otra (Button)

Tags: java, android

Este es mi `Button`:

```
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // así lo abro
            bsb.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            //así lo cierro
            bsb.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
        }
    });
```

Necesito que la función sea abrir, pero si está abierto, sea cerrar.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo de manera correcta?

Comment: bsb es una instancia de que class? Un ToggleButton?

Comment: De `final BottomSheetBehavior bsb = BottomSheetBehavior.from(ll_menu_categorias);` un submenu que aparece desde abajo, un *sheet menu* @mmartinez7

Comment: Tienes el método getState (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.html#getState()). Podrias preguntar si el estado es state_expanded lo seteas con state_collapsed y viceversa,

Comment: Echale un vistazo a esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604599/android-imagebutton-with-a-selected-state

Comment: Gracias! Solucionado, escribelo en una respuesta y la marco como solución :)! @mmartinez7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BottomSheetBehavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.html) proporciona el método [int#getState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.html#getState()), el cual retorna uno de los siguientes posibles estados del boton:

- STATE_EXPANDED,
- STATE_COLLAPSED,
- STATE_DRAGGING,
- STATE_SETTLING.

Para lo que quieres lograr podrias consultar primero el estado del botón antes de setearle el estado:

```
  btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // cerrar
        if(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED == bsb.getState()){
                 bsb.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED); // COLLAPSED tiene mas sentido que HIDDEN según lo que explicas
        }else{
         // podemos asumir que el estado es COLLAPSED dado que estas cambiando entre estos dos estados
         //abrir
         bsb.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }

    }
});
```